# Does CloudFlare's analytics support download statistics on individual files?

Tags: analytics, cloudflare, download

I'm planning on using CloudFlare with our website but I need to make sure that I can still provide download statistics for some of the files which will inevitably be cached.

I couldn't find anything referring to specific files, rather than general page visits.

Is this possible with CloudFlare's analytics in combination with the same analytics that we currently use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not - at least, not on the Pro plan that I use. Cloudflare Analytics is actually fairly limited in what you can see, and there is no download of stats.

In my dashboard I have the following. All graphs allow for daily or hourly 'points' and go back one month maximum.

- Requests Through Cloudflare - a graph of how many cached vs uncached requests occurred.
- Bandwidth - a graph of how much data was used (cached vs uncached) in megabytes or gigabytes.
- Unique Visitors - should be self-explanatory.
- Threats - a graph of 'malicious threats' split into Bad Browser, Human Challenged and Browser Challenged
- A map showing where threats have originated from.
- Top Traffic Origins - table with most popular countries.
- Top Crawlers/Bots - table of crawlers (e.g. Googlebot).
- Various pie charts of savings you've made using Cloudflare such as '90% fewer servers needed' or '80% bandwidth saved'.

It's interesting to look at occasionally, but I've never found it truly useful. If you need stats on specific files you may have to look elsewhere.